# Java Networking NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So, I think VGR might have answered the question. Below is my code for the ServerClient class, however, why would this code make this.out null? If there are any other questions that you have for me, feel free to ask them. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerClient implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, Runnable{
    public static int port = 59519;
    public static String ip = "192.168.0.3";
    public boolean running;
    public Socket socket;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public BufferedReader in;
    public String name = "Unknown";

    public ServerClient(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.running = true;
        System.out.println("Client created: " + name);
    }

    private void code(){
        try (
                PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
            ) {
                String inputLine;
                inputLine = in.readLine();
                this.name = inputLine;
                System.out.println("Listening for messages from " + this.name + ".");
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Message from " + this.name + ": " + inputLine);
                    validate(inputLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + port + " or listening for a connection");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                this.running = false;
            } catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
                this.running = false;
            }
    }

    private void validate(String msg){

    }

    public void send(String msg){
        System.out.println("ServerClient received: " + msg);
        this.out.println(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        code();
    }

    public void start() {

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Msg is probably null, just use a debugger.

Comment: how can you be sure without debugging?

Comment: If `this.out` is a PrintStream, it doesn't matter whether `msg` is null.  It is more likely that `this.out` itself is null.

Comment: @VGR I updated the post. If you would take a look at it that would be great. To me, I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with it, but I'm pretty sure what you pointed out is the problem. TIA

Comment: NPEs are caused by basic programming errors, not by networking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void send(String msg){
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: ServerClient is actually an object used to store client information, and the socket. When I write "this.out.println(msg);" it sends msg to the client through a socket.

Comment: I have to go offline, however, I'll try to add the full code later.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is happening because `this.out` is null.  It is null because there is no code that sets it to a value.  In Java, fields are null/zero/false initially.

I think you want to replace this:

```
PrintWriter out =
    new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

with this:

```
this.out =
    new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

and I'm pretty sure that entire statement should be moved into the constructor.

Comment: *facepalm* Why didn't I see that. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

so VGR answered my question. I had to mess around with my code a bit until I could get it to work, but here's the final product of that class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerClient implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, Runnable{
    public static int port = 59519;
    public static String ip = "192.168.0.3";
    public boolean running;
    public Socket socket;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public BufferedReader in;
    public String name = "Unknown";

    public ServerClient(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.running = true;
        System.out.println("Client created: " + name);
    }

    private void code(){
        try (
                PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
            ) {
            this.out = out;
                String inputLine;
                inputLine = in.readLine();
                this.name = inputLine;
                System.out.println("Listening for messages from " + this.name + ".");
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Message from " + this.name + ": " + inputLine);
                    validate(inputLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + port + " or listening for a connection");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                this.running = false;
            } catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
                this.running = false;
            }
    }

    private void validate(String msg){

    }

    public void send(String msg){
        System.out.println("ServerClient received: " + msg);
        this.out.println(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        code();
    }

    public void start() {
        run();
    }
}
```

Thanks!